# $\mathbb{R}$ endowed with euclidean topology not homeomorphic with $\mathbb{R}$ endowed with specific topology

Tags: general-topology

On $\mathbb{R}$ consider the family $\mathcal{T}$ consisting of $\emptyset,\mathbb{R}$ and al the intervals of type $(-\infty,r)$ with $r\in\mathbb{R}$. This is a topology on $\mathbb{R}$.

Now I have to prove that $\mathbb{R}$, endowed with the euclidean topology is not homeomorphic with $\mathbb{R}$ endowed with the topology $\mathcal{T}$ defined above.

Intuitively, I know this statement is true. But I don't know how to explain why. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 4):

Suppose $\varphi \colon (\mathbb{R},\mathcal{E}) \to (\mathbb{R},\mathcal{T})$ is an homeomorphism, where $\mathcal{E}$ denotes the euclidean topology. Then $\varphi$ induces a bijection $\Phi \colon \mathcal{E} \to \mathcal{T}$, $U \mapsto \varphi^{-1}(U)$ with $\Phi^{-1}(V) = \varphi(V)$. Thus $\Phi \colon (\mathcal{E},\subseteq) \to (\mathcal{T},\subseteq)$ is an isomorphism of ordered sets. But $(\mathcal{E},\subseteq)$ is totally ordered and $(\mathcal{T},\subseteq)$ is not.

Comment: Thanks.. But I've never seen the notation $(\mathcal{T},\subseteq)$.. What does it mean?

Comment: The subset-relation $\subseteq$ defines a partial order on the set $\mathcal{T}$. (Notice that the elements of $\mathcal{T}$ are subsets of $\mathbb{R}$, so for all $U,V \in \mathcal{T}$ the comparison $U \subseteq V$ makes sense.) By $(\mathcal{T},\subseteq)$ is mean the resulting ordered set.

Answer (score 3):

HINT: In the Euclidean topology each set of the form $\{x\}$ with $x\in\Bbb R$ is closed. Is that true in the topology $\mathcal{T}$? Remember that a homeomorphism takes closed sets to closed sets.

Comment: Ooh, in $\mathcal{T}$ these sets aren't closed, there are only open sets of type $(-\infty,r)$. Thanks!

Comment: @JBIBB: You're welcome!